# Proper SQL request with psycopg2 in Python

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I am having trouble using the psycopg2 lib in Python to execute a PostgreSQL query.

This code works :

```
cols = sys.argv[1:]
cur.execute("SELECT "+', '.join(cols)+" FROM table WHERE a=%s", (a,))
```

However, it has a bad SQL injection vulnerability. If I try to do it the proper way :

```
cur.execute("SELECT %s FROM table WHERE a=%s", (', '.join(cols), a))
```

The output is 'col1, col2, col3' for each row that match the filter. So it is just the same string for all and not the actual values from the database. So why does psycopg2 interprets the fields as a string literal ?

Comment: Parameter substitution intended for literals, not for identifiers.

Comment: if it would take join(cols) wothout quoting them you have same injection vulnerability...

Comment: @CraigRinger thanks for the info. This is what it looks like. But is there a way to properly have an identifier that comes from a variable ? That does not sound like a silly problem.

Comment: @ffarquet Escape and quote them. For identifier quoting it is trivial. Wrap them in "double quotes" and double any embedded double quotes so " becomes ""

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so it seems there is no nice way to do it. So I just chose to validate the user input according to section 4.1.1 of the [SQL standard](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html) for identifiers (starts with a letter and then letters, digits, underscores, dashes or dollar).

```
for c in cols:
    if not re.match(r'^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9$_-]+$', c):
            print "Argument is not a valid column name :", c
            sys.exit()
```